# Change thread to subproces or other process

Tags: multithreading, process

I'm wondering if a thread can jump from one process to another process. This is a hypothetical situation. I have a multi-threaded application, when one thread is blocked for too long, I switch it to a subprocess or another process, or maybe another approach - the thread state is saved in a variable or something like that and the thread is killed. The next step is to run the subprocess/process with the data from the saved thread state.

Comment: What language are you using ? and what do you expect to gain from changing a thread to a process ? What is the main problem ?

Comment: The typical answer is no, you can't just tell the OS to move a thread from one process to the other, but that thread can just fork itself and die, conserving its state, but .... why ????

Comment: Just I thinking to better managing, if thread execute to long, just put him in another process, separate it. I think that process management is simpler than threads management, maybe i wrong. Ahmed AEK it's not depend on particular programing language, just is it possible.

Comment: Re, "...the thread state is saved..." That's fine if the entire state of the thread is contained within its call stack or, in other such well defined places,  but what if the thread is also using globals? What if it is using heap objects? What if it is sharing any of that with other threads? What if it was in the middle of updating shared state when it became stuck?

Comment: Solomon Slow this are good questions. I'm not expert in this particular area of IT, but i think that everything is connected between eachother. If thread share some data, other threads must know what thread is currently sharing data - maeaby by some uniqe thread ID - so in this partiqular example, when thread will have jumped to another process it takes new ID and first job in new process is change relations, i mean update old thread id to new one in connected threads.

Comment: Let me ask a different question. Suppose there _was_ a way to move a thread from one process into another. What problem do you think that could solve?

Comment: P.S., It is not necessary for threads to know the identities of other threads with which they share variables. They only need to know when it's safe to access those variables and when it is not safe. That's what _mutexes_ are for.